# Given these constraints. Can I add information to my legend?

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend entries={Region,Signal},
]
    \addplot[
        fill=gray!20, draw=gray!20,
    ] coordinates {
        (0,20)
        (100,20)
        (100,40)
        (0,40)
    };
    \addplot[] coordinates {
        (0,100)
        (100,0)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which looks like:

[image: figure]

I would like to add another line to the legend that says e.g. `t_0 = 2022-07-31 20:11:49 UTC`, but I have the following problem:

1. I can only add text/commands in the `keys` of the `axis` and `addplot`s i.e. only within the `\begin{axis}[HERE]` and `\addplot[HERE]`. I can not add text anywhere else.

I have tried adding an empty plot at the end but it didn't write the legend.

I know these are very rare conditions. Am I out of luck? Or is there any `legend_style, legend_entries` stuff that I could add to the `axis`?

PS: I **cannot** use `\addlegendimage` and `\addlegendentry`. I can only add text in the places I specified above.

Comment: Why you do this? This not explain anything about drawn curves and gray field in diagram. You may consider add this text to diagram title, for example, or to figure caption (if it means time of diagram data acquisition).

Comment: The drawing here has nothing to do with my real figure. It was just a MWE sample I had from a previous question. The figure already has a title with more useful information. I just want to have the information of what `t=0` means somewhere visible in the plot; and given my constraints I think the legend is probably the only reasonable place left. I am open to suggestions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the restraints you state, you can probably still do the following (I leave it to you to decide whether this is semantically reasonble, though):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend cell align=left,
    legend entries={
        Region,
        Signal,
        {$t_0 = {}$2022-07-31 20:11:49 UTC}
    },
]
    \addplot[
        fill=gray!20, draw=gray!20, area legend
    ] coordinates {
        (0,20)
        (100,20)
        (100,40)
        (0,40)
    };
    \addplot[] coordinates {
        (0,100)
        (100,0)
    };
    \addplot[empty legend] coordinates { 
        % at least one coordinate is needed for the plot to be added
        (0,0) 
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another way could be to add the time stamp as extra tick:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend cell align=left,
    legend entries={
        Region,
        Signal
    },
    xlabel={$t$},
    xlabel style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
        anchor=north west,
    },
    ylabel={Hz},
    ylabel style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
        anchor=south east,
        rotate=-90
    },
    extra x ticks={0},
    extra x tick style={
        xticklabel={2022-07-31 \\ 20:11:49 UTC},
        xticklabel style={
            yshift=-1.25em, 
            align=center
        }
    }
]
    \addplot[
        fill=gray!20, draw=gray!20, area legend
    ] coordinates {
        (0,20)
        (100,20)
        (100,40)
        (0,40)
    };
    \addplot[] coordinates {
        (0,100)
        (100,0)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend cell align=left,
    legend entries={
        Region,
        Signal
    },
    xlabel={$t$},
    xlabel style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
        anchor=north west,
    },
    ylabel={Hz},
    ylabel style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
        anchor=south east,
        rotate=-90
    },
    extra x ticks={0},
    extra x tick style={
        xticklabel={2022-07-31 \\ 20:11:49 UTC},
        xticklabel style={
            align=left,
            anchor=south west,
            rotate=30
        },
        ticklabel pos = right
    }
]
    \addplot[
        fill=gray!20, draw=gray!20, area legend
    ] coordinates {
        (0,20)
        (100,20)
        (100,40)
        (0,40)
    };
    \addplot[] coordinates {
        (0,100)
        (100,0)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this adheres perfectly to my constraints. Just as an aside, do you have any suggestions on other ways I can show what `t=0` means given my constraints? The title already has other things. Maybe a second axis environment with only a single custom tick at `t=0` on the top? As long as it only requires text in the places I can write to.

Comment: @user17004502 So, which axis represents *t* then? The *x* or *y* axis? Or am I not understanding the diagram correctly?

Comment: The horizontal axis represents `t`. My idea was adding a custom tick to the top horizontal line where `t=0` (leaving the bottom horizontal line exactly as it is). But yes, maybe this is not clear enough. Probably leaving this information in the legend is the least worst I can do given my constraints.

Comment: @user17004502 May I ask what the vertical axis represents? Which letter would you use to refer to this value?

Comment: I really like your suggestion. Thanks a lot for your answer, it is very informative. I am surprised with the level of customization that can be achieved even with my weird constraints. Most of my plots have these constraints, I have to learn a lot more about all these features/keys.

Comment: In reality my graph is some binned data plotted with `const plot mark right`, and the vertical axis represents a rate in Hertz. Again, thanks a lot for your answer, it helps a lot.

Comment: @user17004502 Feel free to customize these suggestions. I only asked because I think, it would be good to have the unit (or symbol) added to the two axes (which I did in the two last versions).

Answer (score 1):

Strange request ... Information`$t_0 = {}$2022-07-31 20:11:49 UTC` doesn't anything common with for what serve `legend`. As I mentioned in my comment, to my opinion it rather belong to diagram title or to diagram caption.

Diagram title is normally above diagram, but I understood that this is not desired and that this info should be inside diagram. For example as follows:

[image]

Inserting this information into legend, to my opinion, beside to bad looking result, make its information unclear. But this is up to you.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={$t_0 = {}$2022-07-31 20:11:49 UTC},
    title style  = {at = {(0.95,0.95)}, font=\small, inner xsep=0pt, anchor=north east},
    legend style = {at = {(0.95,0.9)}, font=\footnotesize, anchor=north east},
    legend cell align=left,
    legend entries={Region, Signal}
            ]
\addplot[fill=gray!20, draw=gray!20, area legend] 
    coordinates {(0,20)     (100,20)
                 (100,40)   (0,40)};
\addplot[] coordinates {(0,100)   (100,0)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it is a strange request. I am using a PGFPlots code generator (to programmatically generate plots in a script based on some input data), and it currently has some limitations; so I cannot just add arbitrary commands in any place. Sadly I already have some other (more useful) information on the title. Do you have any suggestions for a better place to represent what the `t=0` is? I was also thinking about maybe a second axis environment with a single custom tick on the top. I will keep thinking about it, I agree it doesn't look very good in the legend.